# How can I load data into a RadComboBox via AJAX without using Load On Demand?

Tags: ajax, telerik, radcombobox

I have a page containing five RadComboBoxes that all need to populated from a database (via SQL Server stored procedure).  Currently they are bound to the data using the `OnLoad` event, but that causes the page to load slowly.  I am required to use other features of the RadComboBox (specifically checkboxes) that, according to Telerik's docs, are not compatible with the built-in `LoadOnDemand` feature.

How would I mimic the `LoadOnDemand` feature to reduce the load time of the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, yes, but you still can use the ItemTemplate and put a checkbox element there and use it with Load on Demand.

See the first combobox in this demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultcs.aspx

It will require some more work from you in order to define the template and then manually get the checked items, but it is not impossible.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify the question, my main concern is making the loading/binding of the items asynchronous.  That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: If you use Load on Demand the combos will be empty on page load, e.g. no data will be fetched from the DB, no items will be created, thus the page load time will improve. On opening the combo dropdown an ajax request is sent to the server to fetch the items of that combo. What is concerning you exactly?

Comment: My concern is that the LoadOnDemand and checkboxes features aren't compatible, so I need to implement the ajax request myself.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Have you seen the demo link I posted earlier? There, the first combo has EnableLoadOnDemand = true which means the combo handles the ajax request. You just need to provide ItemTemplate that will include the checkbox and manually handle any check/uncheck logic, e.g. by using jQuery